# Reading 2gb files line by line from Bash script results in "xmalloc:cannot allocate..." error

Tags: windows, bash, shell, mingw32

When opening file descriptors in a bash script and reading files line by line, the script terminates with a memory allocation error after processing 70K lines:

> xmalloc: cannot allocate 11541 bytes (0 bytes allocated)

Environment: 
MINGW32 
Bash: 3.1.20(4)-release (i686-pc-msys)
OS: Windows 7

The size of input files: 1.2 GB each

The script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Left: $1
echo Right: $2
echo >"$1.diff"
echo >"$2.diff"
exec 4<"$1"
exec 5<"$2"
LINECOUNT=0
while [ $? == 0 ]
do
    exec 0<&4
    read LEFTLINE
    exec 0<&5
    read RIGHTLINE

    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        exit -1
    fi

    LINECOUNT=$(($LINECOUNT + 1))
    LINEMOD=$(($LINECOUNT % 1000))
    if [[ $LINEMOD == 0 ]]
    then
        echo Line: $LINECOUNT
    fi

    if [ $LEFTLINE != $RIGHTLINE ]
    then
        echo $LEFTLINE >> "$1.diff"
        echo $RIGHTLINE >> "$2.diff"
        echo Mismatch found
    fi
done
```

As I said above the script works for a long time, processes about 70K lines and then terminates. I assume it terminates because it uses up all the memory that a 32 bit process can take.

The purpose of the script is to open two files of the same format and length and compare them line by line. It creates two output files into where it writes out mismatching lines. I had to write the script because all comparison tools I had at my disposal crashed with "out of memory" errors or hanged. I was surprised when my script also crashed. I had to rewrite the same in C++ to make it work. Now I am trying to understand why the bash script failed. In theory it should not accumulate the file content in memory. Instead it should just read one line at a time and advance the file pointer. I am trying to understand why it crashed. Maybe there is another approach to my problem that you can recommend that I could have implemented as a bash script.

**Update:** Tested the following modification. It also crashed.

```
while IFS= read -u4 -r LEFTLINE && IFS= read -u5 -r RIGHTLINE
do
    LINECOUNT=$(($LINECOUNT + 1))
    LINEMOD=$(($LINECOUNT % 1000))
```

Comment: Have you tried `read -u4` rather than the `exec 0<&4` syntax? So you could do `while IFS= read -u4 -r LEFTLINE && IFS= read -u5 -r RIGHTLINE; do echo "$LEFTLINE"; echo "$RIGHTLINE"; done 4<fileA 3<fileB`

Comment: @Mark Setchell Thanks for the useful recommendation. The code is cleaner and simpler that way. I updated the question. However, it still crashed with the same error.

Comment: Your output files are not on a FAT32 filesystem I hope? No file may exceed 2GB on FAT filesystems. Can you ensure you are using NTFS?

Comment: I am on NTFS. My files are 1'082'479 KB each. They are 2Gb together

Comment: @MarkSetchell it's 4gb actually, but that's not really the point here; It may be related to how bash is reading the files. If there's a leak then there's a leak - If I feed the script /dev/urandom on OSX I see a continuous memory growth of the process as well. There are several posts on-line related to memory leaks in particular versions of bash so this could be the issue.  Unfortunately if there's a leak, you're probably going to have to use a different tool instead of bash. [this looks like it may be related](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=618393). OSX has bash3.2 which fits

Comment: @Petesh, yes, the bug you linked is very similar to what I have. I would expect it to be fixed in OSX recent bash but from what you said the leak is still there. I am going to test cygwin as well soon.

Comment: Based on the simplicity of this program, though, it would be trivial to rewrite it in perl or python neither of which should exhibit the memory leak.

Comment: @Petesh, yes, that's what I said in the question text. Eventually I wrote it in C++ and completed my task but I wanted to come back to it as I wanted to use bash for similar purposes in the future. I didn't know it was a bug and I thought that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Just a small tip: you can replace `echo >"$1.diff"` with `>"$1.diff"` if you just want to clear the file.  And you should put double quotes (") around $LEFTLINE and $RIGHTLINE when you compare them, else the script fails when the files have spaces in them.

Comment: I ran your script on a pair of identical 20 GB files and it used only 10 MB of memory and this did not increase.  Bash 4.1.5, x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the valuable input from the people in the comments to the question the solution was found. Petesh commented correctly that **there was a bug (or many bugs) in previous versions of bash that caused memory leaks**. [Here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=618393) is the link to the ticket provided by Petesh. Fortunately, the leak was fixed in more recent versions of bash. **So the solution is to update bash.** I installed cygwin with the bash version 4.1.17(9)-release (i686-pc-cygwin) and my script completed successfully with only 1.5 Mb of memory consumed without memory increases. John Zwinch also tested Bash 4.1.5, x86_64 and confirmed that the bug was fixed in that version too.

While resolving the issue a few improvements to the script were suggested by Mark Setchell and John Zwinck. The modifications didn't fix the problem but made the script simpler and more reliable with different file formats. The final version of the script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Left: $1
echo Right: $2
>"$1.diff"
>"$2.diff"
LINECOUNT=0
while IFS= read -u4 -r LEFTLINE && IFS= read -u5 -r RIGHTLINE
do
    LINECOUNT=$(($LINECOUNT + 1))
    LINEMOD=$(($LINECOUNT % 1000))
    if [[ $LINEMOD == 0 ]]
    then
        echo Line: $LINECOUNT
    fi

    if [ "$LEFTLINE" != "$RIGHTLINE" ]
    then
        echo $LEFTLINE >> "$1.diff"
        echo $RIGHTLINE >> "$2.diff"
        echo Mismatch found
    fi
done 4<"$1" 5<"$2"
```

Comment: Couple more small improvements you might like: `LINECOUNT=$(($(LINECOUNT + 1))` can be shortened to: `((LINECOUNT++))`; and `$LINEMOD=$((LINECOUNT % 1000))` can be shortened to: `((LINEMOD = $LINEMOD % 1000))`

Comment: Also you should mark your answer as accepted. :) (So it doesn't show up in the list of "unanswered" questions.)